# Extjs handler passes parameter but cannot use the specific parameter even though it's in the button class

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a panel which represents a 'group' with a button for creating a 'proposal' for that group.

I am passing the current group name in a handler.

When the button is clicked it calls onAddProposalBtn.

```
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'panel',
                                        cls: 'currentproposal-container',
                                        id: 'AddProposalPanel',
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                        xtype: 'button',
                                        margins: '0 0 0 20',
                                        cls: 'addproposal-btn green-btn',
                                        hidden: false,
                                        id: 'AddProposalBtn',
                                        scale: 'small',
                                        text: 'Create Proposal',
                                        handler: function(AddProposalBtn) {
                                          var group = me.group;
                                          AddProposalBtn.group = group;
                                        }
                                           }
                                       ]
                                    },
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked the button class is populated but I can't get the group. The output of the console is the 'button' class which includes a populated 'group'. But the actual groupname displays 'undefined'.

```
    onAddProposalBtn: function(button, e, eOpts) {
      var groupname = button.group;
 console.log(button);
 console.log(groupname);
        this.groupname = groupname;
        this.showCreateWindow();
    },
```

What is strange is if I close the proposal window then click the proposal button again it fills in the group name.

Comment: I assume this is happening the first time because the handler is firing after the onAddProposalBtn() method is executed. If you move the content of onAddProposalBtn() into the handler, does it work as expected?

Comment: The reason I have the handler is because the Button and the store are separate and do not share values. The store is in the Group store and the onAddProposalBtn() is called in the Proposal controller.
I would not be able to call "this.showCreateWindow()" in the group store because it would be referring to the group, not the proposal.